# Sort files manually

Tags: windows, sorting

I've got one simple problem (and expected one simple solution, which I didn't find).
I would like to sort files manually (drag and drop) on Windows 10.

I've read a lot of workarounds (e. g. renaming every file and than sort it alphabetically), but is there any more straightforward solution? I know I can disable Auto arrange, but the sorted order is not saved.
I'm willing to install/buy any other third party software, but so far I didn't find any that would cover this demand.

It should:

- Enable me to drag and drop files in any order I want
- Save the order, so when I return there later, the files will be still sorted
- I'm willing to spend free space on my disk (which is the main reason why Microsoft disabled this in the first place)

Any solution will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe this has ever been supported by windows except on the desktop itself, and thats just based on the painting of the icons displayed (they're not really files at all). do you have any examples of this previously being a windows feature? that may help.

Comment: Sort them for what purpose?  Perhaps there is another approach that might solve your problem.

Comment: renaming is going to be the way to accomplish this unless your order is actually something you can sort by, such as newest items first. Then sorting by that is of course easier. If there's logic behind your sort that can be extracted from the file itself, a script could be constructed to sort based on that. Alternatively, it could be possible to create a script that places all filenames in a .csv file, open that with excel, move the cells around to create a new order and construct a second script to rename the files based on that order.

Comment: @FrankThomas on Microsoft forum I found that it was available before Windows XP.


  -SeñorCMasMas primarily for sorting pictures and music. I found there are some picture sorting apps, but I would prefer solution not just for pictures.


  -LPChip I like when the solution to a problem can be as abstract as possible, so let's assume there is no logic in it (which... is my case in reality anyway). I actually like your excel suggestion. But still it's quite uncomfortable to open excel every time I want to rearrange file... but it would work, so thank you anyway ;)

Comment: "Microsoft disabled this" That's highly doubtful. Sorting by any criterion is cheap. Saving a list of 'where the user would like everything' is expensive [data & computationally expensive, because it has to be saved, then looked-up every time.] Fine for one desktop, bad for 'all folders'. Ironically, I suppose, Mac can do this for any folder in Icon view, but no other view… maybe Windows can too if there's a 'no sort' option in the View structure [I don't have a Win machine I can look at right now]

Comment: This is just some random stuff on my desktop, opened as a folder, with no sort & no position alignment [all user choices] dragged around at random. Odd as you like. It will remember this until I change it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/en84J.png

Comment: See also [this](/q/1483846) question for some options. [This](/q/584789) one confirms that it used to be possible.